# Tag custom loop show posts

Tags: loop, tags

i have a posts tag with 'php'.....i am using this code to show all posts tag with 'php' but it not work

```
<?php query_posts('tag=$tag');
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
the_content() 
endwhile; endif ;
?>
```

Comment: Why you are not using `WP_query` or `get_posts` ?

Comment: any example will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 2):

It is not recommended to use `query_posts`. But this is not the problem, Problem is you are using PHP variable in single quotes. `'tag=$tag'`

Consider these examples:

```
query_posts('tag=php');
//OR
query_posts("tag=$tag"); //$tag should output: php
```

*Using `WP_query //Recommended`*

```
$query = new WP_Query(array( 'tag' => 'php' ));
```

Ref: [WP_Query-Tag_Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters) | [query_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and answer.....but it not work.It is possible you post full code.

Comment: I gave you three suggestions. If all of the three are not working then I am sorry I will go back to school to learn code :D
Please try to debug your problem only then someone can help you here :)

Answer (score 0):

There is some changes in code try this

```
$query = new WP_Query(array( 'tag' => 'php' ));
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
  while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    the_content() ;
  endwhile; 
endif ;
```

Comment: after adding this code it makes blank screen...no out put......well i think today is my BAD DAY...simple things goes wrong..btw thanks for this effort.

Comment: ohh. just one change that was syntax error after the_content() add " ; "
my bad..